# Chrome address bar disappeared after update

Tags: high-sierra, google-chrome, fullscreen

I have a weird issue with Chrome (69.0.3497.92 (Official Build) (64-bit)). When I go into fullscreen mode with `CMD + CTRL + F` the addressbar disappears.

It started after the update from the old known theme to the 'new' flat Chrome version. I cannot browse to URLs in fullscreen mode anymore.

To make it completely clear. It is not with the video based fullscreen etc. it concerns every page.

#### Normal view:

[image: In normal view]

#### Fullscreen view:

[image: Fullscreen view]

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: There is a new update, I will find out if this resolved it.

Comment: It works with Ver. 70

Comment: @Buscar웃 I am at version 71, havent seen it for about 2 weeks now indeed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have been fixed in version 70 as I use version `71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)` for 2 weeks now and I haven't experienced failures.

Update (March 17th): 
I haven't had any issues whatsoever, so it seems to be fixed.

Comment: Just had it happen again on: `Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: And it's happened again on: `Version 77.0.3865.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: Hmm, what macOS version are you running?

Comment: This is running on my work PC: Win10 Pro.
I guess this means it's a chrome bug not related to the OS.

Answer (score 80):

1. Open Google Chrome on your Mac
2. Move cursor to top of screen where OS Toolbar is located and click VIEW
3. In the drop-down menu that appears, click "Always show toolbar in full screen"

Comment: That has been said earlier and doesn't work.

Comment: @Knate it worked for me.

Comment: This works (now?) but the point of going fullscreen is to hide all of this, and the way Chrome used to work was to slide down all of this when moving the mouse to the top edge of the screen, effectively going *full screen*, hence the name... It's hard to believe that this behavior could be one of those newfound "features" for dim-witted users, because the default behaviour would be a broken browser UI for any dad- or mom-level user that they can't get out of (and I, a developer, needed to google for it and find it here to get out of it without an actual solution)... :thinking_face:

Comment: yay!!!! thank you so much it drove me crazy for months! it works as required.. when i'm full screen on netflix i won't see that address bar.. but when I open a new tab on chrome on full screen I do have address bar! yay!

Answer (score 7):

Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> on MAC to **show or hide** the navigation bar

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same issue with my chrome and its been driving me insane. I found another google forum where someone was talking about removing the address bar, so I tried the steps in reverse. What I did was go to the view option in the status bar, made sure "always show toolbar in full screen" was checked, went into full-screen mode, saw it was still checked, uncheck it and recheck it, and the address back came back!. This worked for me pretty well, and hopefully, it'll help you out as well. Have a nice day!

Comment: That unfortunately didn't fix it, it does show up indeed but the searchbar doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Based on:
http://osxdaily.com/2018/09/10/disable-chrome-ui-theme-redesign/

I had luck going to:

`chrome://flags/#top-chrome-md`

search for: `"UI Layout for the browser’s top chrome"`

Change to `"normal"` then restart the browser. Then I had tabs and address bar.

Like another answer it appears to toggle something that was not set properly. For me changing this setting back to "default" doesn't appear to undo anything

Comment: I will try this in a bit.

Comment: I found out this is not only with my widescreen but on my MacBook Pro screen too. I just set it to normal and will test it a couple of days.

Comment: Still have the same problem.

Comment: This suggestion worked for me (including still working after going back to "default").

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can exit full screen and maximize the window manually:

1. Click "Exit Full Screen" in the "View" menu.
2. Press and hold the Option key while you click the green maximize button in the top-left corner of an app window
3. If the window is not fully maximized, use the mouse to expand the window to the edges of the screen, with the top border to just below the toolbar.

Comment: That just doesn't answer the question. It is a bug within Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

or..
hover near the top to show the apple functions bar and select `View - Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen`

(this is in reference to High Sierra (10.13.6) and Chrome (Version 81.0.4044.122)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Google Chrome menu problem with my brand new Macbook Pro 2019 - the green yellow & red window controls also wouldn't appear when I hovered towards the top menu bar. I fixed all these issues by putting Chrome in full-screen mode (holding control + green maximize to choose full-screen) then went up to where "View" would be and was able to check off - "Always show toolbar in full-screen mode". I now can go into full-screen mode and hover the mouse to access the window controls and top menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like expected behavior in Mac OS full screen view - the menu bar including the URL bar is hidden unless you move the mouse up to reveal it. From [the official documentation](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-apps-in-full-screen-or-split-view-mchl9c21d2be/mac#apda500bba37ca94):

> In full screen, do any of the following:
>   Show and hide the menu bar: Move the pointer to or away from the top of the screen to access the app’s menus.

As an alternative, you can:

> Maximize the window by pressing and holding the Option key while you click the green maximize button . The window expands, but the menu bar and the Dock remain visible. To return to the previous window size, Option-click the button again.

Or to expand the window to the full width and height of the screen while still showing the menu bar, hold `SHIFT + ALT/OPTION` while clicking the green maximize button.

Comment: It only shows the option bar when I go up with my cursor... Note: It worked before.

Comment: > As an alternative, you can:
Yes, I am doing that right now but it is not optimal as I am using 2 applications next to eachother.

Comment: @Yvan `It only shows the option bar when I go up with my cursor... Note: It worked before.` - what you're describing is expected behavior with Mac OS full screen view. Not sure what was happening before.

Comment: I also got an addressbar now I simply don't.

Comment: @Yvan Yeah. I'm not sure how that was happening before (what mode you were in), but I added to the answer another thing you can do to expand to full width and height of the screen while preserving the menu bar.

Comment: @Yvan if that works for you, please consider accepting and voting up the answer - I could use the points for a bounty I'd like to start on a question I have open. If that's not it, can you describe what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: It doesn't solve my question, therefor I do not accept it... I need it to work with fullscreen mode.

Comment: @Yvan if you can provide more context for why you need full screen mode with a menu bar as opposed to a maximized window, someone might be able to offer another suggestion. What are you trying to achieve by having this setup? You mentioned having another application next to it - what are you doing with chrome as well as the other application? Are you using multiple monitors? Someone would need context like that in order to help any further.

Comment: I am a developer, I use it to test my application without having to find the right desktop. I found a part of the situation out. It only does this on my 'big' monitor, it can't handle the monitor however the resolution is not that much higher. 29" at 2560x1080.

Comment: I also can't type in the URL / Search bar in the middle of the page.

Answer (score -1):

Force quit, reopen and restores defaults

Answer (score -1):

it's still a WIP, but thi plugin can help you with the URLs on full screen mode.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zenhelper/odpfhihammejhokpbbkbhlmhnoipglmc